# Why this code is give error?

Tags: c, macros, output

```
#define cat(x,y) x##y
main()
{
    printf("%d",cat(cat(cat(3,3),cat(3,4)),5));
}
```

Why this is give error?
As per my knowledge O/P should be

```
    cat(cat(3,3),cat(3,4)),5
```

because due to concatenation inner macro is not expanding. Why this is not happening?

Comment: `gcc -E your_file.c`

Comment: What is `##` in `x##y`?

Comment: @karma_geek the macro concatenation operator

Comment: I simply want to know what is the reason of error ?

Comment: `cat(cat(3,3),cat(3,4))` =>  `cat(3,3)##cat(3,4)` <-- error.

Comment: See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/Macro-Expansion.html

Answer (score 3):

call by indirect.

```
#define cat_(x,y) x##y
#define cat(x,y) cat_(x,y)
```

Comment: Can you comment on why calling indirect works?

Comment: Macro function  does not recursively expanded. So must sandwiching another macro function.

Answer (score 1):

If more than one ## operator and/or # operator appears in the replacement list of a macro definition, the order of evaluation of the operators is not defined.

***[Read more here](http://www.serc.iisc.ernet.in/facilities/ComputingFacilities/systems/cluster/vac-7.0/html/language/ref/clrc09numnum.htm)***

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @ryyker yeah check [this](http://www.serc.iisc.ernet.in/facilities/ComputingFacilities/systems/cluster/vac-7.0/html/language/ref/clrc09numnum.htm)

Comment: When you embed stuff like this in your answers to vet the information, it increases likelihood of an up-click.  (if that makes a difference to you)